# FileStream returning null characters every other character

Tags: c#, text, file-io, filestream

I seem to be having some issues with a Filestream in C#. 
I am trying to read the last line from a VERY large text file, 10mb, that is generated by a MSI installer.

The code I am using is:

```
string path = @"C:\uninstall.log";
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    long len = fs.Length;

    fs.Seek(-100, SeekOrigin.End);

    fs.Read(buffer, 0, 100);
}

string foo = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
Console.WriteLine("\"" + foo + "\"");
```

But the output looks similar to this:

```
H E L L O   W O R L D ! ! ! B L A H   B L A H
```

Apparently the stream that is read contains a '\0' (null) character every other character.
Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Try UTF16.  Only a comment.  If I was sure I would post as an answer.

Comment: Unlike `UTF7`, `UTF8` and `UTF32` the property for UTF-16 is called `Unicode`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Encoding.UnicodeEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.unicodeencoding.aspx) instead. Your file is encoded in UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: Yup, that was it. Weird though, you think that the filestream would skip null characters or any decoder would.

Comment: Skipping null bytes would be weird and unexpected behaviour for `FileStream` - there are plenty of file formats where null bytes are meaningful!

Comment: Since null characters are valid UTF-8 characters, the `FileStream` should not skip them. Glad it's working, though!

Answer (score 7):

The file is probably a UTF-16 file, not a UTF-8 file. Just try using `Encoding.Unicode` instead of `Encoding.UTF8`.

Comment: Yes that seemed to be the issue, I'm awarding the answer to David though as he told me how to fix it vs what was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the file is actually UTF-16 encoded.  Change UTF-8 in your GetString().